# Testing a callback with Moq in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Learning Moq, and need some help with testing a callback result.  The structure is: I have a `DateManager` object that has a dependency on an `DateServer` object that makes async calls to a server.

`DateServer.GetValidDate` will take a date string in `yyyy-MM-dd` and will execute the given callback with a string in the same format.

How do I setup the mock server such that the test below will pass?  A simple mock setup would be that my mock DateServer would simply return whatever string is provided to it (in the callback).

Here's my setup.  I think I have most of this structure correct, but need help filling in the ???? in the code below.  If I should have tested the callback return better, then I'm interested in that as well.

```
public interface IDateServer
{
    // with a currencyPair (ie: USDCAD), verifies that the given date is 
    // valid for a potential transaction.  
    // Callback is used to process the returned result, which is a date string.
    void GetValidDate(string currencyPair, string date, Action<string> callback);
}

public interface IDateManager
{
    void GetDate(string currencyPair, string dateCode, Action<string> callback);
}

[TestClass]
public class DateManagerTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetDateTest()
    {
        ManualResetEvent ar = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        Mock<IDateServer> server = new Mock<IDateServer>();
        DateTime tradeDate = new DateTime(2016, 2, 17);

        server.Setup( ???? );

        IDateManager dm = new DateManager(tradeDate, server);

        string ret = "";
        dm.GetDate("USDCAD", "2016-02-17", (string s) =>
        {
            ret = s;
            ar.Set();
        });

        ar.WaitOne();

        Assert.AreEqual<string>(ret, "2016-02-17");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to want to test the `DateManager`, you want to make sure that the `DateManager` calls the `GetValidDate` method of the `DateServer` dependency with a specific set of parameters. The method does not return anything so there is no need for a setup.

As the `DataServer` that calls the callback method is not the class that is being tested, it is not important whether the callback is really called. You'd have to test this in a separate test of the `DateServer`.

Therefore, the following test method should validate that the `DateManager` passes the right parameters  to the `DateServer`(right in this case = the parameters that were passed to the `DateManager`):

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetDateTest()
{
    Mock<IDateServer> server = new Mock<IDateServer>();
    Action<string> callback = (string s) => { };
    IDateManager dm = new DateManager(server.Object);
    dm.GetDate("USDCAD", "2016-02-17", callback);
    server.Verify(x => x.GetValidDate("USDCAD", "2016-02-17", callback));
}
```

Comment: So we called `dm.GetDate()`, and then `Verify()` checks that `GetValidDate()` gets called properly.  This makes sense, and for this case is most of the way.  However, what happens if my `DateManager` manipulates the returned result before the last callback?  I still want to check the string returned in the callback.  How to do this?

Comment: @gdbj AFAIK the `DateServer` is the one that is supposed to call the callback. So from the point of view of a test for the `DateManager` there is no need to check whether the callback is really called. In a separate test for the `DateServer`, you'd provide a dummy callback (no Mock) to the `DateServer` as you did in your sample code. Also, if the `DateManager` is at some point expected to call the callback, you'd provide a dummy callback and check whether this was called the right amount of times. As the calls cannot originate from the mock `DateServer`, it was the `DateManager`.

Comment: Yes, I see now that you are correct.  Any assertion checks are not required since the result is contrived by the setup itself.  Took me a bit to work that out.

Answer (score 2):

This will setup a callback for `GetValidDate` and will give you access to any parameters passed to the method when it is called on the mocked interface.

```
Mock<IDateServer> server = new Mock<IDateServer>();

const string testDateString = "2016-02-17";
const string testCurrencyPair = "USDCAD";

server.Setup(obj => obj.GetValidDate(It.IsAny<string>(), 
                                     It.IsAny<string>(), 
                                     It.IsAny<Action<string>>()))
      .Callback<string, string, Action<string>>((currencyPair, date, callback) =>
      {
            //  The parameters passed into GetValidDate (see below) 
            //  will be available in here.
            Debug.WriteLine(currencyPair);
            Debug.WriteLine(date);
      });

server.Object.GetValidDate(testCurrencyPair, testDateString, null);
```

From my understanding of the `Callback` method this will only notify you that the mocked method was actually called and with what parameters.

Comment: I'm not sure this is clear for me.  I want to assert that testDateString matches what comes back in the callback.

Comment: In the callback replace the `Debug` calls with `Assert.AreEqual(testDateString, date)`.

Comment: The parameters specified in the callback, i.e. `currencyPair`, `date` and `callback`, will contain whatever values are passed in any call to `server.Object.GetValidDate` even if called from within `DateManager`.

Comment: Just as a side note I assume that `DateManager` constructor takes a `IDateServer` as the second argument. If so, then when you do `new DateManager(....)` I would pass `server.Object` which will represent the actual mocked instance of your interface.

Comment: Wish I could also mark your answer as correct, since the Callback feature has proven to be very helpful for me.

Comment: Glad it could help in some way.